# Android: Posting Date object to PHP using HTTPClient

Tags: php, android, post, httpclient

I am trying to post a Date object `Date date = new Date()` to a remote PHP script using HTTPClient but it seems like `NameValuePair` does not accept any other Java objects other than a `String`? Would appreciate if you can guide me how to post a `Date` object using `HTTPClient`

Here's my code

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
Date date = new Date();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringObj", "Test")); //No error
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateTime", date));  //Error here

try{

    String response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://remotewebsite/test.php", postParameters);

catch{
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to string. Make sure `date` is not empty/null (I didn't see in your code that you used the `date` object with some of the methods from the `Date` class)

For example:

```
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dateTime", new Long(date.getTime()).toString()));
```

Comment: I know I can cast it to string. But is there no way to pass in a date object directly?

Comment: Nope, since the `BNVP` constructor accepts only strings for the `values`.